# Regular expression to check if string has at least one and up to 3 words and more than one hashtag in python

Tags: python, regex

```
s1 = 'Makeupby Antonia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls #abhcosmetics'
s2 = 'Makeupby Antonia asia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls'
s3 = 'Makeupby Antonia'
s4 = '#makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls #abhcosmetics'  
s5 = 'Makeupby Antonia asia america #makeup #makeupartist'
```

Regex should be able to match `s1` and `s2` only because normal words count is up to 3 and these have more then one hashtag.

I am able to select normal words using `\b(?<![#])[\w]+`
and
I am able to select hashtag using `[#]{1}\w+`
but when I combine the expression then it does work.

How can I make final regex using these individual regex which can also track count?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Why not split the string on space and count how many words start with a hashtag?

Comment: I think you're holding the regex hammer and seeing everything as nails. This is one of the issues that regex is famously bad at. Aran-Fey's solution would work quite well, probably faster than regex, and be easier to read to boot.

Comment: (P.S. @Aran-Fey you should write that up as an answer -- this is classic XY problem territory, and I'd upvote it)

Comment: Yes I want to solve this using regex only. If I wont find any solution then only I will come to basic spliting and counting. Because I have to query for such string in huge database. loading all data and iterating it over then checking would be very time consuming. So I want to solve it using regex

Comment: You dont have to necessarily iterate. There are several solutions made for situations where you have lots of data. `pandas` for example could be of great use

Comment: `s4` also has more than one hashtag and up to 3 words, so shouldn't that be `True`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Thanks I have corrected title of this question.

Answer (score 4):

### The sane solution

Split the text into words and count how many of them start with a hash sign.

```
def check(text):
    words = text.split()

    num_hashtags = sum(word.startswith('#') for word in words)
    num_words = len(words) - num_hashtags

    return 1 <= num_words <= 3 and num_hashtags > 1
```

```
>>> [check(text) for text in [s1,s2,s3,s4]]
[True, True, False, False]
```

### The regex solution

```
import re

def check(text):
    pattern = r'(?=.*\b(?<!#)\w+\b)(?!(?:.*\b(?<!#)\w+\b){4})(?:.*#){2}'
    return bool(re.match(pattern, text))
```

I'm purposely not going to explain that regex because I don't want you to use it. That feeling of confusion you're probably feeling should be a strong sign that this is bad code.

Comment: In regex solution, regex is not ignoring string having more than 3 words.

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor Oops, I got the condition backwards (it was checking for 1-3 hashtags and at least 2 words). Fixed now.

Comment: ***Now*** it's fixed for real. **More** reasons not to use regex.

Comment: Thanks @Aran-Fey, but its still not ignoring s5 in question

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question and if you can assume words are always before tags you can use `r'^(\w+ ){1,3}#\w+ #\w+'`:

```
for s in ('Makeupby Antonia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls #abhcosmetics',
          'Makeupby Antonia asia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls',
          'Makeupby Antonia',
          '#makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls #abhcosmetics',  
          'Makeupby Antonia asia america #makeup #makeupartist',):
    print(bool(re.search(r'^(\w+ ){1,3}#\w+ #\w+', s)), s, sep=': ')
```

This outputs:

```
True: Makeupby Antonia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls #abhcosmetics
True: Makeupby Antonia asia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls
False: Makeupby Antonia
False: #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls #abhcosmetics
False: Makeupby Antonia asia america #makeup #makeupartist
```

Comment: Thanks, updated (but both expressions are not exactly equivalent - the last implies a trailing space)  - [update] I was answering a now deleted suggestion to use `(\w+ ){1,3}` instead of `(\w+|\w+ \w+|\w+ \w+ \w+)`.

Comment: You had a trailing space after `(\w+|\w+ \w+|\w+ \w+ \w+)` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a lot of room for optimization (maybe with dependencies/fewer loops) but here's a non-regex solution as discussed in comments:

```
s_list = [s1, s2, s3, s4]

def hashtag_words(string_list):
    words = [s.split(" ") for s in string_list]
    hashcounts = [["#" in word for word in wordlist].count(True) for wordlist in words]
    normcounts = [len(wordlist) - hashcount for wordlist, hashcount in zip(words, hashcounts)]
    sel_strings = [s for s, h, n in zip(string_list, hashcounts, normcounts) if h>1 if n in (1,2,3)]
    return sel_strings

hashtag_words(s_list)

>['Makeupby Antonia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls #abhcosmetics',
 'Makeupby Antonia asia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls']
```